# Связь модели сериала со списком жанров

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

У меня есть модель сериала, которая в свою очередь должна содержать в себе коллекцию моделей жанров.

Как организовать такую связь правильно? При попытке указания в модели списка, или же массива жанров, связать это дело правильно не удалось.

Модель сериала:

```
public class Serial
{
    public int SerialId { get; set; }
    public string SerialTitle { get; set; }
    public string SerialDescription { get; set; }
    public string PreviewImage { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public Genre[] Genres { get; set; }
    public int SeriesCount { get; set; }
    public int SeriesReleased { get; set; }
    public string Studio { get; set; }
    public int Country { get; set; }
}
```

Модель жанра:

```
public class Genre
{
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

При таком раскладе, в базе данных появляется у таблицы жанров дополнительное поле `SerialId`, туда можно указать только один айди сериала.

Comment: Ну это же многие-ко-многим, а не один-ко-многим. https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.8.php

Comment: а почему у вас в сериале есть ссылка на массив жанров (кстати, лучше селать его списком), а в жанре нет ссылки на список сериалов?

Comment: @tym32167, я делал его коллекцией `IEnumerable<Genres>` но эффекта 0, а у жанра не должно быть ссылок на сериалы, или я просто пока не понял как это сделать.

Comment: в смысле не должно быть? У вас жанр связан с сериалом отношением многие-ко-многим. То есть и жанр должен содержать список сериалов этого жанра, и сериал должен содержать список жанров для сериала.

Comment: а в данный момент ваша модель показана как связь один-ко-многим. То есть один сериал ко многим жанрам, но один жанр ссылается только на один сериал.

Comment: @tym32167 Согласен, беда в том что я не понимаю как эту свзяь организовать, т.к. при добавлении поля со списком сериалов к жанру, `ef` отказывается делать миграцию. `Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Genre.Serials' of type 'IEnumerable<Serial>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`

Comment: Конечно отказывается, ведь если вы уже предыдущую модель накатили, то изменение связи один-ко-многим не обновляется автоматом без потери данных на связь многие-ко-многим

Answer (score 1):

У вас отношение многие-ко-многим, делается так:

```
public class Serial
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

    public Serial()
    {
        Genres = new List<Genre>();
    }
}

public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Serial> Serials { get; set; }

    public Genre()
    {
        Serials = new List<Serial>();
    }
}
```

https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.6.php

Comment: а почему не `List<Genre> Genres`? Как элементы туда добавить? Кастить или метод писать?

Comment: Понял, там написано: `На данный момент (версия EF Core 2.0) Entity Framework Core не позволяет создавать отношение многие-ко-многим без связующей сущности. В нашем случае такой сущностью является класс StudentCourse. Фактически связь многие-ко-многим здесь разбивается на две связи один-ко-многим: один Student - много StudentCourse, один Course - много StudentCourse.`

Comment: @LLENN она не разбивается, это и есть суть связи многие-ко-многим, в БД оно все равно будет с промежуточной таблицей, а вам видимо придется эту промежуточную таблицу и в код добавить.

Comment: EF Core пока не умеет many to many автоматически: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/

Comment: @АндрейNOP, похоже что даже 3я не умеет: `Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Serial.Genres' of type 'List<Genre>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`