# Как сделать Many to Many?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

Делаю как в примере Many to Many, но у меня появляется ошибка:

Ошибка  CS1061  "CollectionNavigationBuilder" не содержит определения для "WithMany", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "WithMany", принимающий тип "CollectionNavigationBuilder" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Хотя должно быть все правильно:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                    .HasMany<Point>(s => s.Points)
                    .WithMany(c => c.Items)//Тут ошибка
                    .Map(cs =>
                    {
                        cs.MapLeftKey("ItemRefId");
                        cs.MapRightKey("PointRefId");
                        cs.ToTable("ItemPoint");
                    });

public class Item
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Point> Points { get; set; }
    }
public class Point
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: это что? EF? EF Core?

Comment: @tym32167 По всей видимости - да. И по все видимости здесь вот это не работает `cs.ToTable("ItemPoint")`

Comment: @tym32167 А как тогда сделать?

Comment: @АртёмОконечников да что? :)

Comment: @chilo5432 я вам задал вопрос, вы не ответили, потому я не знаю, что вам и как сделать.

Comment: @tym32167, это core с ef и code first. Извините что сразу на ваш вопрос не ответил

Comment: @tym32167 автор уже ответил :)

Comment: в EF Core связь многие-ко-многим делается через [промежуточную таблицу](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.6.php). Автоматом эта таблица не сгенерится, EF Core такое пока [не поддерживает](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/)

Comment: [Возможный дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/995752/179763)

Comment: @tym32167, Понял, спасибо. Попробую так сделать